# Hive: external partitioned table from Avro

Tags: hive

Is it possible to create an external table in Hive based on Avro files that also add columns for the directory partitions:

Let's say I have data stored in `/data/demo/dt=2016-02-01` and so on. I then tried the following but I get 0 rows when I select from the table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE demo
  PARTITIONED BY (date STRING)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED AS AVRO
  LOCATION '/data/demo/'
  TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url' = 'hdfs:///path/to/schema.avsc');
```

I tried without the `PARTITIONED BY` clause and then I get the records but obviously without the `key=value` directory partitions. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the partition name is in your case `dt`, not `date`, you have to use `PARTITIONED BY (dt string)`, and then you still need to add the partitions to the metastore :

```
ALTER TABLE demo ADD PARTITION (dt='2016-02-01')
```

If you have several partitions, you can [repair](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)) the table, and it will add them automatically :

```
msck repair table demo
```

Comment: Thanks, the date (instead of dt) was a typo by the way.